# How to put textfield inside image?

Tags: html, css

Could anyone show me a code snippet that produces the "search box" that is similar to the one in this example: www.dx.com?

It surprised me that googling "textfield inside image" only gave me all the results of "image inside textfield".

Comment: It is not valid to put a textfield "inside" an image -- IMG elements *cannot* contain content. However, it may be "layered above". Pull out your favorite DOM/CSS-inspection (IE Developer Tools, Firebug, whatever Chrome has, etc.) tools and take a look at how www.whatever.com did it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put inside an image other element, but you can do the following to achieve this effect:

Use a `css` as:

```
<style>
    .search-container{background:url(your/image/path) no-repeat top left;width:200px;height:50px;}
    .search-container input{width:150px;}
    .search-container button{width:40px;}
</style>
```

And `html` like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" /> <button>Search</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the `search-container` will be with a background image and inside you can put your search form (input and button).

if you want the input without the 'default' style your can reset with:

```
.search-container input{border:none;background:transparent;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers pointed out the method you were looking for is invalid.  You are essentially layering the text field on top of an image, and hiding the borders and backgrounds of the field so the only thing visible is the image.

They are using absolute positioning to set the text field and button on top of the image, removing the borders and the backgrounds so the elements are essentially invisible, showing the image behind it.  Here is a fiddle with a simple example.  http://jsfiddle.net/a2pQ2/2/

Here is the html

```
<div class="searchbox">
    <input type="text" class="search" id="search" value="Search in 80,000+ Gadgets...">
    <button id="btnSearch" type="button" class="btn_search"></button>
</div>​
```

and the css

```
.searchbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 367px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(http://tctel.com/search.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.searchbox .search
{
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    width: 287px;
    outline: none;
}
.searchbox .btn_search
{
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 71px;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}​
```

So searchbox is the container, it has a background image that is 367px wide and 36px high.  So we set it to position relative so we can absolutely position the children.

.search is the text field. It is set to position absolute, and I set it to 6 px from the top and the left to match the borders of the image, set the height to 24 for the same reason.  And I hid the border and outline.

.btn_search is the button and I just positioned it to the right, and hid the border, made the background transparent, and made the cursor change on mouseover.